# Rails custom route unable to invoke view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to implement a custom route in rails

```
match '/:slug' => "products#get_by_slug", :as => :get_by_slug
```

If I dont have a corresponding view (get_by_slug.html.erb), I get a Template missing error
If I add that view, I get a Routing Error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"products"}
```

How can I get my custom route to invoke the corresponding view?

Many Thanks

Comment: what do you see when you rub rake routes?

Comment: What URL are you trying on your browser?

Comment: You probably have an error in the get_by_slug.html.erb template. Does it generate error if you make the file empty?

Comment: @dimuch yup, there was a back button in there that didn't belong. Thanks. I can mark yours as the answer if you type it in below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error in the get_by_slug.html.erb template. Does it generate error if you make the file empty?